# Spring Cloud AWS 3.x and Parameter Store Integration

Tags: spring-cloud-aws

Is integration between Spring Cloud applications and AWS Parameter Store the same with Spring Cloud AWS 3.x as it has been in the past (as previously outlined [here](https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/current/reference/html/index.html#integrating-your-spring-cloud-application-with-the-aws-parameter-store))?

I am trying to map Parameter Store properties into the following class:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "rds")
@Validated
@Data
public class MyParamStoreProperties {
  @NonNull private String password;
  @NonNull private String username;
}
```

In addition, I have the following in my microservice's `src/main/resources/bootstrap.yml` file:

```
spring:
  config:
    import: aws-parameterstore:/config/myapplication/rds
```

I don't see a similar description in the [latest Spring Cloud AWS 3.0.1 documentation](https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/3.0.1/reference/html/index.html#configuration-properties) as I've seen in previous documentation, so I am wondering how the setup is supposed to be from this point forward. In other words, if I have Parameter Store values of `/config/myapplication/rds/username` and `/config/myapplication/rds/password`, will these get mapped into `MyParamStoreProperties` correctly with AWS Parameter Store as the property source now that I'm using Spring Cloud AWS 3.0.1?